# getconfig() for Community Connectors, how to employ user input

Tags: looker-studio

The Community Connector feature is very new, and I have searched, there isn't much information. We are building a Community Connector to enable Data Studio to pull API data from Google My Business Insights.

the getconfig() function is described here: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getconfig

We can display our configuration options to the user, that was easy, but the API reference is unclear what the next step is: how to pass the user input to the next step. Pardon me if I am not using the proper terms here.

```
    var config = {
    configParams: [
      {
      "type": "SELECT_SINGLE",
      "name": "SELECT_SINGLE",
      "displayName": "Select a Location",
      "helpText": "Pick One!",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": locationName,
          "value": name
        },
        {
          "label": "altLocationName",
          "value": "altName"
        }
      ]
    },
    ]
  };
  return config;
}
```

The preceding code displays properly to the user and the user can make a selection from the pull-down in Data Studio when making an initial data connection. But to repeat the question another way: how do we access the selection that the user chose?

Answer (score 5):

The `getData()`, `getSchema()`, and `getConfig()` functions are all called with a parameter (which is called "request" in the documentation). The parameter is an object containing various info at each stage.

- At the `getConfig()` stage, it includes a property called `languageCode`, in my case set to `'en-GB'`.
- The `getSchema()` stage is provided a property called `configParams`, which is essentially the result of all the settings in `getConfig()` after the user has set them.
- Finally, `getData()` gets the most info, including whether this request is for extracting sample data for google to run heuristics on, and most importantly: again the `configParams`.

Here's what a sample `request` object might look like:

```
{                               //------ Present in:
  languageCode: en-GB,            //////-Only getConfig()

  configParams: {                 //////-getSchema() + getData()
    SELECT_SINGLE: altName          ////-+
  },                                   //

  scriptParams: {                  //////-Only getData()
    sampleExtraction: true           ////-|
    lastRefresh: 'new Date()'        ////-+
  },                                   //

  fields: [                        //////-Only getData()
    { name: FooAwesomeness },        ////-|
    { name: BarMagicality },         ////-|
    { name: BazPizzazz }             ////-+
  ]                                    //

  dimensionsFilters: [             //////-Only getData()
    [{                                 // |
      fieldName: "string",           ////-|
      values: ["string", ...],       ////-|
      type: DimensionsFilterType,    ////-|
      operator: Operator             ////-+
    }]                                 //
  ]                                    //
}                                //------
```

---

> **Do note**
>   that the `name` field in your code, currently set to `SELECT_SINGLE`, would be better suited to be called `location` because that it how you'll access it later on.
>   In this way you would
>   access:
>   `request.configParams.`**`location`**
>   rather than
>   `request.configParams.`**`SELECT_SINGLE`**
>   :)

---

> **Also note**
>   that the format for specifying a configuration screen has been updated. Your configuration would now be able to be done as follows:
>
> ```
> function getConfig(request) {
>  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
>  var config = cc.getConfig();
>  config
>      .newSelectSingle()
>      .setId('location') // You can call this "location"
>      .setName('Select a Location')
>      .setHelpText('Pick One!')
>      .addOption(config.newOptionBuilder()
>        .setLabel('Location Name')
>        .setValue('value'))
>      .addOption(config.newOptionBuilder()
>        .setLabel('Alternate Location Name')
>        .setValue('altValue'))
>
>  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);
>  config.setIsSteppedConfig(false);
>
>  return config.build();
> }
> ```

See: [Connector API Reference](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference)
See: [Build a Connector Guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/build)

Answer (score 0):

The user selections will be passed to [getSchema()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getschema) and [getData()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata) requests under `configParams` object.

Using your example, let's assume the user selects `altLocationName` in the configuration screen. In your getSchema() and getData() functions, `request.configParams.SELECT_SINGLE` should return `altName`.